# Which question is better: precise or generic?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, voting, asking-questions

While the [Stackoverflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advises questions to be crafted describing **specific problems**, I can't help but to notice that many or not most of the highest voted questions are vague and at best generic.

Here's an example (I note that it is an old question, however, and might not reflect guidelines). [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)

Also, many of them have been closed due to the quality of question, but because they are generic, they get a lot of hits from searches and page view and naturally very high in votes.

So here's my contemplation. Should I make my questions more generic and less specific so it appeals to more people? In other words, keeping the scope of my question wider so that it can potentially help more people - or should I avoid the risk of getting slammed in down votes and flags and just be very specific, assuming in both cases the question is not a duplicate and is well written.

### Update

To better explain my dilemma, say I was about to post a question on a stored procedure issue that I am facing. If I were to put a code dump and be very specific, someone might be able to help me resolve in code level. However if I choose to make it language-independent and ask on a high level on the concepts of stored procedure, it might potentially reach more people who has similar issues on different database systems, and I would still be able to extrapolate the answer that I need with some experimenting.

Comment: They're not mutually exclusive.  You can describe a very specific problem that millions of people have.

Comment: Note; Using older questions as examples doesn't necessarily reflect current posting guidelines.

Comment: Usefulness is usually measured by how many people find it useful. If your question is too specific, you might be the only person that finds it useful. however, if it's too generic, it may end up being too broad. you should strive to be somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Servy My question was, given a problem, it is my contemplation as to the degree of specific-ness, which would of course affect the number of people that it would be relevant to. Your response seems to be begging the question. It is not a matter of whether they are exclusive (although you can only choose one approach and get different results), and it most certainly is not a question of how many million people it is relevant to.

Comment: @Trobbins I agree with you. I should have been clearer to state that those post, which might not reflect posting guidelines, continue to get a lot of views and votes.

Comment: Canonical questions are better when they are more broad, so that they can be applied to any relevant scenario. Most questions, however, are specific problems that people are really experiencing, and most people on the site who write answers have a better chance of answering your question if your question is more specific.

Answer (score 6):

You've pulled an example question from the *early* days of the site.  What was on topic then isn't a good example of what's on topic *now* even if it's been upvoted a lot.

However, that *particular* question is pretty good, even if it's a short question; many people are confused as to what metaprogramming in Python is, and this will help enlighten those who are looking for answers on the subject.

Now, to your direct question:  I would encourage you to **be specific**.  Something that is specific and objective will be received a lot better than something that's unspecific and subjective.